# One Drive as Reparse Point

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, deviceiocontrol, reparsepoint

Consider a following standalone source code which I am experimenting on Win 10 Fall Creators Update Version    10.0.16299 Build 16299

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <memory>

    #if !defined (REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_HEADER_SIZE)  // 

    // Note:
    // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552012.aspx for information about
    // the following structure.
    //
    typedef struct _REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER
    {
        ULONG   ReparseTag;
        USHORT  ReparseDataLength;
        USHORT  Reserved;
        union
        {
            struct
            {
                USHORT  SubstituteNameOffset;
                USHORT  SubstituteNameLength;
                USHORT  PrintNameOffset;
                USHORT  PrintNameLength;
                ULONG   Flags;
                WCHAR   PathBuffer[1];
            } SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer;
            struct
            {
                USHORT  SubstituteNameOffset;
                USHORT  SubstituteNameLength;
                USHORT  PrintNameOffset;
                USHORT  PrintNameLength;
                WCHAR   PathBuffer[1];
            } MountPointReparseBuffer;
            struct
            {
                UCHAR   DataBuffer[1];
            } GenericReparseBuffer;
        };
    } REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER, *PREPARSE_DATA_BUFFER;

    #define REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_HEADER_SIZE  FIELD_OFFSET(REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER, GenericReparseBuffer)
    #endif

    #if !defined(IO_REPARSE_TAG_CLOUD_7)
    #define IO_REPARSE_TAG_CLOUD_7                  (0x9000701AL)   
    #endif 

    struct file_handle_close
    {   
        void operator()(void *handle) const
        {   
            if (static_cast<HANDLE>(handle) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {   
                CloseHandle(static_cast<HANDLE>(handle));
            }   
        }   
    }; // end of file_handle_close structure

    typedef std::unique_ptr<void, file_handle_close>  file_handle_uptr;


    bool is_link(DWORD file_attrib)
    {
        return ((file_attrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT) && !(file_attrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE));
    } // end of is_link()

    union reparse_data_context
    {
        char                 buff[REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_HEADER_SIZE + MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE];
        REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER  reparse_data_buff;
    }; // end of reparse_data_context union


    void foo(const std::string& var,const std::wstring& path_name)
    {
        WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA attr_ctx;
        if (GetFileAttributesExW(path_name.c_str(), GetFileExInfoStandard, &attr_ctx) == 0)
        {    

            DWORD  error_code(GetLastError());
            std::cout << "Error occurred "<< error_code << "\n";
        }
        else
        { 
            std::cout << var << '\n';
            std::cout << "attr_ctx.dwFileAttributes  :" << attr_ctx.dwFileAttributes << '\n';
            bool islink = is_link(attr_ctx.dwFileAttributes);

            if(islink)
            {
                file_handle_uptr  handle_uptr(CreateFileW(path_name.c_str(),
                                                          FILE_READ_EA,
                                                         (FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE),
                                                          0,
                                                         OPEN_EXISTING,
                                                        (FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT),
                                                        0));
                HANDLE  handle(static_cast<HANDLE>(handle_uptr.get()));
                if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                {
                    std::cout << "CreateFileW failed with : "<<GetLastError()<<'\n';
                    return;
                }

                DWORD ret_len;
                reparse_data_context rctx;

                if(!DeviceIoControl(handle,
                                    FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT,
                                    nullptr,
                                    0,
                                    rctx.buff,
                                    sizeof(rctx),
                                    &ret_len,
                                    nullptr))
                {
                    std::cout << "DeviceIoControl failed with : "<<GetLastError()<<'\n';
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    ULONG  reparse_tag(reinterpret_cast<const REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER*>(rctx.buff)->ReparseTag);
                    if (!IsReparseTagMicrosoft(reparse_tag))
                    {
                        std::cout << "Not a supported reparse tag" << std::endl;
                        return;
                    }
                    if (reparse_tag == IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK)
                    {

                        std::wstring  target_name;

                        {
                            size_t len = static_cast<size_t>((rctx.reparse_data_buff.SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PrintNameLength) / sizeof(wchar_t));
                            const size_t another = len;
                            std::wcout << "Target " <<  std::wstring(static_cast<wchar_t*>(rctx.reparse_data_buff.SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PathBuffer) +
                                                                     (rctx.reparse_data_buff.SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PrintNameOffset / sizeof(wchar_t)),
                                                                     len);
                        }

                        {
                            size_t len = static_cast<size_t>((rctx.reparse_data_buff.SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameLength) / sizeof(wchar_t));

                            std::wcout << "Target " << std::wstring(static_cast<wchar_t*>(rctx.reparse_data_buff.SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PathBuffer) +
                                    (rctx.reparse_data_buff.SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameOffset / sizeof(wchar_t)),
                                    len);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(reparse_tag == IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT)
                    {
                        // Do something similar to previous block
                    }
                    else if(reparse_tag == IO_REPARSE_TAG_CLOUD_7)
                    { 
                       std::cout << " this is not a valid Reparse Point"<<std::endl;
                       // How to resolve a target for this ?
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << var << "  is not a link or junction "<< '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    int main()
    {    
        std::wstring path_name = L"C:\\Users\\someuser\\OneDrive";

        foo("OneDrive",path_name);
        return 0;
    }
```

This is the code that I use to resolve the target of one drive which is treated as `IO_REPARSE_TAG_CLOUD_7` by `GetFileAttributesExW` function.

I know that `_REPARSE_DATA_STRUCTURE` has the information only for `SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer` and `MountPointReparseBuffer` and it does not have any fields related to reparse points such as One Drive.

I checked the windows driver kit's (for fall creators update) `ntifs.h` file to see if the structure is updated to support the One Drive. However that doesnt seem to be case.

I also tried to fetch the One Drive target information from the `SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer` and `MountPointReparseBuffer` as done in first if block. However, it ended up giving me garbage.

**Questions:**

1) How do I correctly determine the target for REPARSE_POINTS such as One Drive?

2) Windows 10 Fall Creators update SDK adds more of such REPARSE_POINT tags. 
What is the general thumb rule to treat them (i.e source REPARSE_POINTS) if one can not resolve the target for it (e.g. One Drive) ? As a file or as a directory  ?

Comment: Since the tag isn't a [name surrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365511), I wouldn't expect either `SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer` or `MountPointReparseBuffer` to apply. You have the `GenericReparseBuffer` to read the opaque data for backup and restore. In an I/O request, the reparse is handled by a filter driver -- or maybe right in the I/O manager since it's a Microsoft tag.

Comment: As to whether it's a file a directory, that's what `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` tells you. For example, Windows has both file and directory symbolic links, which use the same `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK` tag.

Comment: do you want to detect which files are online only in Onedrive folder and which are downloaded (new files on demand feature of Onedrive)?

Comment: @magicandre1981... I just want to resolve this new type of symbolic link and find its target...and nothing else....

Comment: @eryksun...ahhh stupid me... you are right...I do have the FILE attribute data returned from `GetFileAttributesExW` which can tell me if the source (i.e the One Drive path) is directory or file...

Comment: the best here use `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` with `FileAttributeTagInfo` which return to you [`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TAG_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364216(v=vs.85).aspx) where exactly both - `FileAttributes` and `ReparseTag`